# How to convert JSON string to MTLModel - Mantle

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

Is there any way in mantle to convert a `JSON` data to `MTLModelObject` directly, I have gone through the documentation and haven't found a simple way to do so.

It seems there is only support for converting `NSDictionary` to `MTLModelObjects` and vice versa.

Comment: why cant you first parse your data to `NSDictionary` then convert it ..

Comment: I can do it, i am just wondering if there is a direct method to do it via mantle, it seems weird, also i have to convert it while rendering cells inside cellForRowAtIndexPath so i want a more optimised way to it if possible.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON string you're working with?

Comment: It can be any JSON string, i don't want to convert the JSON string to dictionary and then to my model object.

Answer (score 0):

Mantle can not convert JSON string to model automatically. Override `JSONTransformerForKey` method and implement ur own NSValueTransformer by using NSJSONSerialization convert JSON String to NSDictionary